# finding location of a point along the arc distance in matlab

Tags: matlab, position, distance

I have a parabola y=a*(x-alpha)*(x-beta) where a, alpha, beta are known
let x1,y1 be initial points on the above parabola. I now have to cover a distance D along the arc from the initial point. The aim is to get the final position on the parabola after covering the required Arc distance.

One method is to keep checking from initial position to end point of parabola and check whether the integral is equal to the required distance. But this algorithm takes ages to complete as I need to do this many times.

Is there a faster way to do this ?

Comment: Probably more suited to http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a line distance on a parabola is not obtained by integration per se. I replaced your a with \gamma for convenience.

```
y = gamma(x-alpha)(x-beta) -> gamma*x^2 + (-gamma*alpha - gamma*beta)*x + alpha*beta*gamma
```

Substitute:

```
a = gamma
b = -gamma*alpha - gamma*beta
c = alpha*beta*gamma
```

So one can write:

```
y = a*x^2 + b*x + c
```

From this formula (parabola) the focal point `f` is determined by:

```
f = (1-D)/(4*a) - (-D)/(4*a)
```

In which

D = b^2 - 4*a*c

Now first define `p` as the perpendicular distance from a location on the curve to the vertical axis of symmetry `x_p`:

p = -b / (2*a) - x_p;

From this the arc length is calculated by:

```
h = p/2
q = sqrt(f^2+h^2)
s = h*q/f + f* ln (h*q/f)
```

In which s is the paramatric representations of your curve. The length of a curve is found by using two points s and then the distance between those points, so:

```
Distance = s_1 - s_2 = (h_1*q_1/f + f * ln (h_1*q_1/f)) - (h_2*q_2/f + f * ln (h_2*q_2/f))
```

With some simplifications:

```
Distance = (h_1*q_1 - h_2*q_2)/f + f* ln (( h_1 + q_1) / (h_2 + q_2))
```

To implement it fully in MatLab is up to you for now. Let me know if you run into any problems.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This is a nonlinear equation: you are given x1,y1 and seek x2, y2. x2 and y2 must satisfy the parabola equation and they must satisfy the arclength equation along a curve. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Arc_length

So that integral gives you the second equation. Now you have two equations and two unknowns - look up matlab fsolve http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

assume the integral can't solve analytically (Can it?) then just solve it numerically using integrate - should still be much faster than just brute force search...

If you need to do this many times, make sure that the previous solutions are given as initial guesses for the next fsolve / integrate calls

Comment: Which contains an integral which was the whole point of the question. I am working on a non-integral solution.

Comment: Try mine, it does not involve integral

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what are you using this for. But let me try to help you anyway

Well, this problem is not so hard to solve anallitically. I mean, it's just a simple line integral of 1 over a parabole. And good for you, it's been done before. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Length_of_an_arc_of_a_parabola

All you need to do is to find the symmetry axis, not hard, X = (alpha + beta)/2, and the focus length (a little bit trickier, but if you google that I'm sure you'll find it). And I found it for you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574688/what-is-the-focal-width-of-a-parabola shows the canonical form of the parabole, so all you need to do is to factor your equation (http://www.math-prof.com/Alg2/Alg2_Ch_40.asp)

Now the equation you need to solve is not pretty. Put everything in terms of p and let MatLab solve it for you (it shouldn't take forever).